When lagrangian fibrations are equivalent?
Given a $2n$-dimensional symplectic manifold $\mathcal{M}$ and two different lagrangian fibrations $\pi_1:\mathcal{M}\rightarrow \Gamma_1$ and $\pi_2:\mathcal{M}\rightarrow \Gamma_2$, with $\Gamma_1, \Gamma_2\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ convex sets, under which general conditions there exists an isometry that factorizes through the projection maps $\pi_1,\pi_2$, i.e., $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f=\pi_1\circ\pi_2^{-1}$, showing then that you can get $\Gamma_2$ from an affine transformation on $\Gamma_1$.
